# Issue with multithreading on Yosemite with R and accelerate

Tags: r, osx-yosemite, accelerate-framework

My R implementation on Mavericks was linking the accelerate BLAS library (instead of the standard R-provided one).

After a clean install on Yosemite I tried to link to accelerate with

```
ln -sf /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/Current/libBLAS.dylib libRblas.dylib
```

(as suggested by Zachary Mayer [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~nmv/2013/07/09/for-faster-r-use-openblas-instead-better-than-atlas-trivial-to-switch-to-on-ubuntu/#comment-86)).

The link works, I think (otherwise I would have got an error calling the library functions during the benchmark).

On the other hand trying the notorious R 25 benchmark I did not see any improvement.

I tried on the same laptop the new RRO (Revolution R Open), that includes intel MKL and the test went from ~30 s to ~5 s.

Is it possible that the Apple library for Yosemite is not offering multi-threading anymore?

Comment: [These](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/APIDiffsMacOSX10_10SeedDiff/frameworks/Accelerate.html) are all the changes to the Accelerate framework in 10.10 and here's the [WWDC 2014 presentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDgQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdevstreaming.apple.com%2Fvideos%2Fwwdc%2F2014%2F703xx9ich9e8mkn%2F703%2F703_whats_new_in_the_accelerate_framework.pdf%3Fdl%3D1&ei=88VIVNuyNMLfsAT47IGoDQ&usg=AFQjCNFyUUO4DOCugRI6JW7BprexICQ0OQ&sig2=qzGSOR02nTSEfo9inKkzlQ&bvm=bv.77880786,d.cWc&cad=rja) on it.

Comment: Can you post the shell commands that you did to do the linking?

Comment: @hrbrmstr I posted the sym link in the body of the question above

Comment: Accelerate still uses multiple threads on Yosemite.  Can you use instruments to get a time profile while your benchmark is running?  That will show what library/functions are actually being used.